# problem openning a window in python using tkinter with button

Tags: python, tkinter

everyone, I am using Tkinter and I want to open a window after clicking on the button but I have this problem that when I run  the program it will open the window not the button and the button is completely useless
this is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()


def addApp():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
                                          filetypes=(("executable", "*.exe"), ("allfiles", "*.*")))


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="OpenFile", padx=10,
                     pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=addApp())
openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="RunApps", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42")
runApps.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: replace `command=addApp()` with `command=addApp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `command=addApp()` to `command=addApp`